# Permissions on actions and pages

Tags: zend-framework, permissions

When using Zend_Acl, there is only a permission check on a specific module/controller/action ... Now, when I have custom urls for pages, not all pages have their own mdouel/controller/action. And I'd like people to see some pages but not all, there is no way to do this with Zend_Acl, correct? 
So should I create a new permissions system for the pages?

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Acl` will handle everything you need for access control. Your job is to define the resource and privileges. This means you can add permissions to any request. It sounds like you have an ACL algorithm that you copied from ZF manual or some other place online and your trying to adhere to that as if it is a standard. Zend_Acl never says you have to stick to their method.

Now, to your problem. Because you have the same `module/controller/action` for every page, you should treat that as one resource and then you could define page level privileges based on a param of your custom URL that you mentioned.

Simply stated, you can do this:

```
$acl->allow('role', 'Module:Controller:Action', array('UrlParams'));
```

Don't forget, `Zend_Acl::allow` is resource and privilege based NOT `module/controller/action` based. See below:

```
$acl->allow('role','resource',array('privileges'));
```

Answer (score 0):

So check the permissions on all controller actions:

```
$this->allow('userGroup', 'controller');
```

in that way instead checks the permissions only and exclusively to a single controller action:

```
$this->allow('userGroup', 'controller', 'action');
```

I hope to check out a help

Comment: All pages have the same module/controller/action, but in a page are multiple actions loaded (widgets). So the permissions on controller/action is easy and works, but I'm confused on how to do it on page level

Comment: I do not understand why all the pages use the same controller and the same action! :S

Comment: A page is a collection of widgets. So a page has to be rendered and all the widgets has to be converted to correct HTML-code. All the widgets have their own module/controller/action (as a normal zend request). To process all the widgets, the request have to be processed by 1 action.

Comment: ok now everything is clear to me, but sorry I can not help you! :S

Comment: No problem :-)
Thanks for you time anyway!!